# Algorithm constraints check failed on signature algorithm

Tags: java, jboss, certificate, bouncycastle, tls1.2

Am getting error :

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: Additional certificat
e path checker failed.
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:362)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:259)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
        ... 73 more
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: Additional certificate path checker failed.
        at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.RFC3280CertPathUtilities.wrapupCertF(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:292)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:357)
        ... 79 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed on signature algorithm: SHA1WithRSAEncryption
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.AlgorithmChecker.check(AlgorithmChecker.java:278)
        ... 83 more
```

during a handshake

I have located my java.security file in the path `jdk/jre/lib/security`
and changed properties

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=
jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=
```

So now no algorithmus are on the list, but I still getting same error !?

My certificate is signed with SHA1WITHRSA / RSA 1024 Bits , and I need to use that one.

Anyone have any Idea what could I try also , java version 1.8.0_141, running on JBoss 6.2